# Evaluating $|\frac{1}{2}(|a\rangle \otimes|b\rangle+|b\rangle\otimes |a\rangle) |^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

I have a quantum state of 3-qubits : $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle (|a\rangle \otimes|b\rangle+|b\rangle\otimes |a\rangle) + \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle (|a\rangle \otimes|b\rangle - |b\rangle\otimes |a\rangle)$.

What's the probability that it is in the $|0\rangle$ state if I measure it (one of the qubits) in the $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$ basis?

I'm expecting that it will be $|\frac{1}{2}(|a\rangle \otimes|b\rangle+|b\rangle\otimes |a\rangle) |^2$ but I'm not sure how that is equal to $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}|\langle a|b\rangle|$ (see Page 7 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.3097.pdf)).

We know $|a\rangle,|b\rangle, |0\rangle, |1\rangle \in \Bbb C^2$

Could someone please explain.

I think this is more of a math question so I am asking it here instead of Physics SE.

Comment: what kind of product do we have here?

Comment: I think you should move the question to Physics Stack Exchange, they are much more well versed in Quantum Mechanics